# Video tag not showing preview on iphone all browsers. and also not working control properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, video

I'm working on html5 video tag, after recording the video, I show it on an HTML page by using jQuery. but the video at first did not show preview frame, it show only the Resume button. After playing by using the Resume button, it can't show automatically the Resume button after the video end. But it works perfectly in android devices.

[image]

Here, First I need to make preview image with resume button. Then, after end the video play I need to make first stage.
Here, what I tried:

```
            const recordedMedia = document.createElement("video");
            recordedMedia.controls = true;
            // recordedMedia.autoplay = true;
            recordedMedia.setAttribute('playsinline', 'true')
            // recordedMedia.setAttribute('data-wf-ignore', 'true')
            // recordedMedia.setAttribute('data-object-fit', 'cover')
            recordedMedia.setAttribute('preload', 'metadata')
            recordedMedia.setAttribute('type', "video/mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.**

By simply adding #t=0.001 at the end of the video file url, we are telling the browser to skip the first millisecond of the video. When you do this, even iOS Safari will preload and show that specific frame to the user.

So the code looks like this:

```
<video>
  <source src="path-to-video.mp4#t=0.001" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**Solution 2.**

WebKit does not preload media data on iOS to avoid using unnecessary bandwidth, but you can override the default with the preload attribute:

```
<video controls preload="metadata" src="...">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```